# Find $\lim_{x\to \infty}{(\frac{\sqrt{x^2-x}}{x} + \frac{1}{4}\sin{\frac{2}{x})^{x^2+\sin{3x}}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I need to find
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2-x}}{x} + \frac{1}{4}\sin\frac{2}{x}\right)^{x^2+\sin(3x)}
$$

So I do this:
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty}{{\left[\left(1+ \frac{\sqrt{x^2-x} + x\sin{\frac{2}{x}}-4x}{4x}\right)^{x}\right]}^{\frac{x^2+\sin{3x}}{x}}}=e^{{\lim_{x\to \infty}{{\frac{\sqrt{x^2-x} + x\sin{\frac{2}{x}}-4x}{4}}^{\frac{x^2+\sin{3x}}{x}}}}}=e^{*}
$$

$$
*={\lim_{x\to \infty}{{\frac{\sqrt{x^2-x} + x\sin{\frac{2}{x}}-4x}{4}}{\frac{x^2+\sin{3x}}{x}}}} = {\lim_{x\to \infty}{\frac{\sin{\frac{2}{x}}{(x^2+\sin{3x})}}{4}}} \\
= {\lim_{x\to \infty}{\frac{\sin{\frac{2}{x}}x^2+\sin{\frac{2}{x}}\sin{3x}}{4}}} = {\lim_{x\to \infty}{\frac{\sin{\frac{2}{x}}x^2}{4}}} = \frac{1}{4} \frac{\sin{\frac{2}{x}}}{\frac{1}{x^2}}
$$

Applying L'Hopital I get that the the limit is $x$, which isn't true. Where am I wrong? Also, I'd like to avoid L'Hopital but I am unable to. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take logarithm of the expression
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2-x}}{x} + \frac{1}{4}\sin\frac{2}{x}\right)^{x^2+\sin(3x)}
$$
that gives
$$
(x^2+\sin 3x)\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2-x}}{x} + \frac{\sin(\frac{2}{x})}{4}\right)
= \frac{\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2-x}}{x} + \frac{\sin(\frac{2}{x})}{4}\right)}{\frac{1}{x^2+\sin 3x}}
$$
Now use L'Hospital, and remeber that what you get is the *logarithm* of the original limit

Comment: This is going to be a painfull process. :-)
Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If
$$L=\lim_{x\to a} f(x)^{g(x)}\to 1^\infty,$$ then $$L=\exp[\lim_{x \to a}(g(x)(f(x)-1)]$$ $$= \exp[\lim_{x\to \infty} [(x^2+\sin 3x)((1-1/x)^{1/2}+\frac{1}{4}\sin (2/x)-1)]$$
Next use $(1+z)^k=1+kz+k(k-1)z^2/2+..., \sin z =z-z^3/6+...$ if $|z|<<1.$
$$L= \exp[\lim_{x\to \infty} [(x^2+\sin 3x) \left(1-\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{1}{8x^2}+...\frac{1}{4}(\frac{2}{x}-\frac{8}{6x^3}+..)-1\right)]$$
$$L=\exp[\lim_{x\to \infty} [(x^2+\sin 3x) \left(-\frac{1}{8x^2}+O(x^{-3}\right)]=\exp[\lim_{x\to \infty}-\frac{x^2+\sin 3x}{8x^2}]=e^{-1/8}.$$

Comment: What does "exp" mean? Is it exponent? If this is the case, I haven't studied that yet. Nevertheless, thank you for your answer!

Comment: Yes exp is is exponential and so is e. Check that your answer finally invilves $e$ so you have to leanr, Just type exponential in the internet to see a lot of help.